# Sitecore SPEAK UI set selected row of ListControl

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-speak-ui

I have a SPEAK UI dialog with a ListControl bound to a [custom JSON datasource](http://laubplusco.net/creating-simple-sitecore-speak-json-datasource/). This works and the ListControl is correctly populated. My JSON data looks something like this:

```json
[
  {
    "itemId":"{BA26159A-194D-4A3C-9D1A-DA9472F11BE0}",
    "selected":true
   },
   {
     "itemId":"{E651D0CD-0E7E-4903-8E26-0D1D5A168E69}",
     "selected":false
   },
   {
     "itemId":"{E651D0CD-0E7E-4903-8E26-0D1D5A168E70}",
     "selected":false
   }
]
```

Is there a way to ensure the relevant row of the ListControl is selected (`"selected":true`) when the dialog loads?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the ListControl's selected item ID like this: this.MediaResultsListControl.viewModel.set({selectedItemId:"ITEMID"})

**(Sitecore.Speak.app instead of this during dubuging in the console)**

If you call this.MediaResultsListControl.viewModel.selectedItemId() you can see the selected item has been set by the above method.

Wondering on page load, if you can set the ListControls selected item id, from the page code manually using this method?

Looking at the JS for the list control. It calls this on click of a row.     Wonder if you can replace this to trigger selected row?

```js
selectRow: function (row, rowModel) {
  this.$el.find(".active").removeClass("active");
  row.addClass("active");

  this.model.set("selectedItem", rowModel);
  this.model.set("selectedItemId", rowModel.get("itemId"));
},
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I will give this a shot. I've currently got code which sets the selectedItemId like this `app.JsonList.set('SelectedItemId', data)` which seems to persist the value on the control, but does not highlight the row.

Comment: Yeah i'm getting the same issue myself. Wondering if its a SPEAK bug, or maybe its too late in the life cycle of the control?

Comment: Added comment to answer

Comment: I don't understand where I'd place this code? In my JsonDatasource.js or into the script referenced by the PageCode of my dialog?

Comment: Id put it in the pageCode so after your retrieve data from the JSON datasource. Call the code to set the selected item index of the List Control

Comment: Not sure where/how I can get a reference to the `row` and `rowModel` objects?

Comment: If you have a look at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MikeRobbins8u2\Website\sitecore\shell\client\Business Component Library\Layouts\Renderings\ListsAndGrids\ListControls\ListControl.js You can see how the objects are created. You might be able to hit those methods or recreate the functionality?